# adjust div margin top using variable - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a diva and its height is auto calculated using jquery using

```
  $(window).load(function(){
  $(window).resize(function(){
   var height = $(this).height() - $("#header").height() + $("#footer").height() - 35
   $('#content').height(height);
})
$(window).resize();
  });
```

I have another div with id `content2` and I want to set the value stored in the variable `var height` as its margin-top. How can I do this??

Thanks in advance...`:)`

blasteralfred

Comment: u dont need `$(window).resize();` that's just silly unless you really need it to happen on load as well  and it should be `$(document).ready();`

Comment: @Val: Why would he not need it to happen on load as well? The real WTF is that he's not calling the inner function with some name, rather than invoking an event directly.

Comment: @tomalak i meant the last `$(window).resize();` which triggers a window resize function he created above it. because he can use css to give margin-top on window load its just stupid, because javascript could hold more instructions at a later time and u totally forgot about it, and it will take u along time to realise why something else tomorrow don't work as it should

Comment: @Val: I know you did. Perhaps you had not noticed that he needs to _change_ `margin-top` when the page layout changes.

Comment: @tomalek he does do that when window resizes, fair enuf on windows load he should use css, to give it the right initial height. not trigger something you have just created, when a window changes size the `$(window).resize(...)` function is triggered

Comment: @Val: Yes, I know what `$(window).resize(...)` does. Not really sure what point you're trying to make at this moment in time.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the `.css()` method.

```
  $(window).load(function(){
    $(window).resize(function(){
      var height = $(this).height() - $("#header").height() + $("#footer").height() - 35
      $('#content').height(height);
      $('#content2').css('marginTop', height); // <-- set here
    });
    $(window).resize();
  });
```

Comment: `.css('margin-top',height)` is better coz it may not work cross browser `marginTop`

Comment: @Val actually `marginTop` is the JS style attribute notation. `margin-top` is not valid in normal JS since there is a `-` in the middle. jQuery knows that and normalizes it. jQuery itself uses `marginTop`

Comment: i used `margin-top` .. is there any prob??

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#content2').css('margin-top',height);
```

Answer (score 0):

//Calculate the height of the offset needed.

```
var height = $('.navbar-fixed-top').height() + $('.navbar-static-top').height() + 70;
```

//Then on click on the navbar tab change the offset of the div according, to the top of the window

```
$('#r_overview').click(function () {
    $(window).scrollTop(($('#hackathon_overview').offset().top)-height);
});

$('#r_rules').click(function () {
    $(window).scrollTop(($('.rules_row').offset().top)-height);
});
```

Hope this helps